# In sequences sunburst, how to give a child the same color of parent?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, colors, sunburst-diagram

What to do to give a child the same colour of parent but lighter, I used the following to generate colour

```
  var color = d3.scale.category20b();

 .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
```

this code gives a random colour for each node.
[first image : random colour](http://s25.postimg.org/4yvf1dfen/image.jpg)

the next image is what I need, my code produce it randomly.
[Gradient colour](http://s25.postimg.org/rc35o6gcf/image.jpg)

I want to make the colour of child is lighter than the colour of parent.

Sorry, I put my result images as a link because I do not have enough reputation.
thank you

Answer (score 3):

This was an interesting one. The bulk of the work was in setting up the colors and associated web page types. I had weird issues when trying to use `d3.interpolateString()` and have shelved that for later investigation. In any case, here is the preparation piece:

```
var brewerColors = d3.entries(colorbrewer);
// offsets 1-5 look too similar
// offsets 6-13 offer the greatest contrast
// offsets 4 and above are no good
var brewerOffset = 9;
var pageTypes = ["home","product","search","account","other","end"];
var colors = [];
var pages = [];
for (var ct=0; ct<pageTypes.length; ct++) {
    var colorBucket = brewerColors[ct + brewerOffset].value[pageTypes.length];
    for (var ct2=0; ct2<colorBucket.length; ct2++) {
        pages.push(pageTypes[ct] + (ct2 + 1));
        colors.push(colorBucket[ct2]);
    }
}

var ramps = d3.scale.ordinal()
    // do not reverse if center colors are lighter than edge colors
    .domain(pages.reverse())
    .range(colors);
```

After that, filling the shapes with the appropriate colors was simple:

```
var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    ...
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return ramps(d.name + d.depth); // e.g. product1, home2, etc.
    })
    ...
```

Here is a complete working [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHjg3UhQCYOTFF6lotol?p=preview).

**NOTE:** I suggest you fork the plunk so all is not lost if it gets inadvertently deleted later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I saw this example but it is not useful with my code, because I don't know the database contents , I want to give the child the same colour of its parent.

Comment: You will need to know the types of events you are sequencing. If you list them as `pageTypes` in the example above, the rest should fall into place. Have you tried that?

Comment: could you please check my sunburst, because I can not do your advice
http://plnkr.co/edit/XrIMel857leFN79zoHor?p=preview

Comment: As you noted previously, the solution I presented does not scale beyond a relatively small number of event types. The only way to adapt it to your situation would be to combine your event types into a few generalized categories. But depending on your use case, this might not be desirable.